# Taking picture in Android with Intent lags / is really slow

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, lag

I have a problem with taking a picture in an Android app. I am using a Galaxy Tab A7 and would like to create a possibility to take a picture. I implemented the camera with an intent (as recommended by Android):

```
 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

 startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO);
```

Unfortunately it takes about 5 seconds until the preview screen appears (where it shows the buttons "repeat" and "ok". Is there any way to speed up the camera and remove the lag after taking the picture? I tried it in a new Thread but it does not make a change.

Comment: Your code will not produce a normal image file. No file at all. You get only a thumbnail.

Comment: Install some other camera apps on your device.

Comment: I am not sure but maybe doing it through ActivityResultLauncher might help a bit(https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#register).

Answer (score 0):

`startActivityForResult` is deprecated. There is a better way to take pictures or record videos in 2022, that is `ActivityResultContracts`.

You can take a small image and it will be saved in a bitmap with: `ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview`

Or you can use `ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture` to take a picture and save it into a URI.

It is really simple to implement.

Refer to the documentation for more info and a tutorial:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts
- https://medium.com/swlh/intro-to-androidx-activity-result-apis-taking-a-picture-6013c3852c0b